# CUDA programming assignment

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I am trying to set only the first element of an array to 5.0 (say). ie, just one of the thread shall set a values and rest of the other threads don't do anything.

Here is my complete code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

#define GPUERRCHK(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

void writeBuf( char * fName, float * out_frame, int dim )
{
    FILE * fp = fopen( fName, "w+" );
    int baseIndx = 0;
    for( int i=0 ; i<dim ; i++ )
    {
        for( int j=0 ; j<dim ; j++ )
        {
            fprintf( fp, "%f ", out_frame[ dim + j ] );
        }
        baseIndx += dim;
        fprintf( fp, "\n" );
    }
    fclose( fp );

}

__global__ void kernel( float * s1, float * s2, int dim, int * hx, int *hy, float *hT, int nHeaters )
{
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;
    int offset = x + y*blockDim.x*gridDim.x;


    if( offset < 1 )
    {
    s2[0] = 1.0;
    }

    __syncthreads();

}



int main()
{
    srand48( time(NULL) );
    int dim = 1024;

    float *dev_s1, *dev_s2;
    GPUERRCHK( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_s1, dim*dim * sizeof(float) ));
    GPUERRCHK( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_s2, dim*dim * sizeof(float) ));
    GPUERRCHK( cudaMemset( dev_s1, 0x00, dim*dim * sizeof(float) ));
    GPUERRCHK( cudaMemset( dev_s2, 0x00, dim*dim * sizeof(float) ));



    //heaters
    int *dev_hx, *dev_hy;
    float *dev_hT;
    int nHeaters = 20;
    GPUERRCHK( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_hx, nHeaters * sizeof(int) ));
    GPUERRCHK( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_hy, nHeaters * sizeof(int) ));
    GPUERRCHK( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_hT, nHeaters * sizeof(float) ));


    //init heaters on cpu
    int * hx, *hy;
    float * hT;
    hx = (int*) malloc( nHeaters * sizeof(int) );
    hy = (int*) malloc( nHeaters * sizeof(int) );
    hT = (float*) malloc( nHeaters * sizeof(float) );
    for( int i=0 ; i<nHeaters ; i++ )
    {
    hx[i] = (int) ((float)drand48() * (float)dim) + 5;
    hy[i] = (int) (drand48() * dim) + 5;
    hT[i] = (float) (drand48() * 100) + 50;
    }

    //transfer hx, hy, hT to GPU
    GPUERRCHK( cudaMemcpy( dev_hx, hx, nHeaters * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ));
    GPUERRCHK( cudaMemcpy( dev_hy, hy, nHeaters * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ));
    GPUERRCHK( cudaMemcpy( dev_hT, hT, nHeaters * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ));


    float *out_frame = (float *) malloc( dim*dim*sizeof(float) );


    // run kernel
    int nThreadsPerBlock = 16;
    int nBlockX = (dim+nThreadsPerBlock-1)/nThreadsPerBlock;
    int nBlockY = (dim+nThreadsPerBlock-1)/nThreadsPerBlock;
    kernel<<< dim3(nBlockX, nBlockY), dim3(nThreadsPerBlock, nThreadsPerBlock) >>>( dev_s1, dev_s2, dim, dev_hx, dev_hy, dev_hT, nHeaters );
    GPUERRCHK( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    GPUERRCHK( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );


    // collect result
    GPUERRCHK( cudaMemcpy( out_frame, dev_s2, dim*dim * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ) );


    int f=1;
    char fName[100];
    snprintf( fName, 100, "out/file_%04d.data", f );
    writeBuf( fName, out_frame, dim );


    cudaFree( dev_s1 );
    cudaFree( dev_s2 );

    free( out_frame );
}
```

When I run this, the file contains all zeros. How do I achieve what I plan to achieve?
What could be the problem?

Comment: If you are going to post a "my code isn't working" question, please make sure you post *the actual code* (and that code should be as concise and minimal as possible) which has the problem, because what you have posted clearly isn't the code you are compiling and running.....

Comment: I have put in the exact code I am compiling now. Please help..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in writeBuf(..) @line:

```
fprintf( fp, "%f ", out_frame[ dim + j ] );
```

dim is 1024 and you are accessing elements from 1024 to 1024+dim-1 and that is why you never see the first element.
The correct line should be:

```
fprintf( fp, "%f ", out_frame[ baseIndx + j ] );
```